# how to make chrome console code permanent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I pretty new to using console for chrome but I have a question. When using the console for chrome, the code that you input is volatile. Is it possible to change this setting so that the code works every time you visit a website?

Thanks

Comment: The code? do you mean the console logs?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you're experimenting with JavaScript, have you tried JSFiddle?

Comment: If you want to edit the code on a page where you don't have access to the core files, you can use plugins like GreaseMonkey (for Firefox) or TamperMonkey for Chrome. The scripts you add there will change the workings on the page (what you can access). You can also add Stylish (at least for Firefox), which is a user-CSS based plugin. And no, you cannot save the changes you make in the console/dev console.

Comment: You want chrome snippets. Or a user script manager

Comment: If for example I type "document.getElementById('nav-jobs').innerHTML = 'Hello';" in the console, I want it to save so every time I visit stackoverflow.com for example, it should change jobs tab to Hello!

Comment: that's cross site scripting you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Are you asking for this? If I understand your question, that preserves your log.

Comment: That won't make the code run, that will just keep the log from being cleared every time the page changes.

Comment: I believe this with a on page load event *may* work.

Answer (score 0):

you can create and save snippets on sources tab and run it with `ctrl + enter`

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: yes.. you can create as many snippets .. right click on the blank area below script snippet #1 and click `new` to create new snippet.. add any javascript code and `ctrl + s` to save.. this will be saved across chrome and you can just run it with `ctrl + enter`

Comment: So every time I visit a page, I need to press the run button. Can this be done automatically every time I visit a page?

Comment: you want to run js script on any website (whose codebase you don't have access to ) ?

Comment: Yeah I want to run my own js on any website.